# VB6 P&D Installations, "The destination file is in use..."

Tags: vb6, installation, packaging

I am maintaining an application written in VB6 and we currently use package and deployment wizard to create installations for our project. When most users try to install this software they get the error message:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\vbajet32.dll
The destination file in in-use. Please ensure that all other applications are closed.
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a specific way that I can avoid this happening by changing something in the installation files/setup or writing some kind of script? I have no experience writing packaging/deployment scripts which is part of why we use P&D wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Your installer is probably trying to replace a dll (vbsjet32.dll) that is being used by another app.

Maybe they are using Access (or another app) while trying to install and it's already using the dll.

You may be able to get around it by making sure users have closed all open programs before installing, or you may have to write custom code to handle it.